# Electron cannot create a browser window inside the main window

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I need to create a browser window inside the main window and following the documentation is only leading me to some errors.

```
$('#browser').on('tap', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var browserWindow = window.createWindow({width: 500, height: 500});
  mainWindowloadURL('http://stackoverflow.com');
});
```

The exception I'm seeing is

> Uncaught Exception: ReferenceError: $ is not defined at Object. (/Users/Machado/githubRepos/jfalcao-v2/main.js:18:1) at Module._compile (module.js:413:34) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10) at Module.load (module.js:357:32) at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12) at Module._compile (module.js:413:34) at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10) at Module.load (module.js:357:32)

Comment: So what are your errors?

Comment: Sorry about that:`Uncaught Exception:
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Machado/githubRepos/jfalcao-v2/main.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)`

Comment: It looks like jQuery isn't loaded. See [I can not use jQuery/RequireJS/Meteor/AngularJS in Electron.](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.37.6/faq/electron-faq/#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron).